# Attempted to load class "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase" from the global namespace. Did you forget a "use" statement?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, integration-testing

I've written integration Test cases in Symphony using phpunit.
The Test cases are working fine but when I'm trying to execute command

```
app/console debug:router
```

I'm getting error, says

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found in
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Test/KernelTestCase.php
>   on line 23**
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException]
>   Attempted to load class "PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase" from the global
>   namespace.

Did you forget a "use" statement?

Any Clue, why am I getting this error ?

Comment: Maybe You are using test environment while running this command?

Comment: too less informations: which phpunit version? which php version? how does your setup look like? it seems the autoloader is not configured correct... composer? soo many misstakes that could be made...

Answer (score 4):

Run

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit symfony/test-pack
```

it works for me